Relative differential of vector bundle
I am reading Ogus and Vologodsky's article on nonabelian Hodge theory in characteristic $p$ (https://math.berkeley.edu/~ogus/preprints/anonhodge.pdf). It uses the terminology ''vector groups'' in the first section, which rarely appeared elsewhere to my feeling.
So, as far as I understand, a vector group $\mathbf{T}$ over a scheme $X$ means $\operatorname{Spec}(\operatorname{Sym}^\bullet(T^\vee))$ for a locally free sheaf $T$ on $X$, just as a geometric vector bundle in Hartshorne Exercise 5.18. However we only record its group scheme structure given by the vector bundle, or in terms of symmetric algebra giving by $x \mapsto 1 \otimes x + x\otimes 1$.
Now let $L$ be a $T$-torsor on $X$ for Zariski topology. Then the article forms an affine scheme $\mathbf{L}$ for $L$ without mentioning what exactly it means. I guess it is still $\operatorname{Spec}(\operatorname{Sym}^\bullet(L^\vee))$ as $L$ is still a locally free sheaf and this guess works quite well until the following statement:
\begin{equation}
\Omega_{\mathbf{L}/X}^1 \simeq \pi_{\mathbf{L}}^* T^\vee
\end{equation}
where $\pi_{\mathbf{L}}$ is the structure morphism from $\mathbf{L}$ to $X$.
This equality is quite essential for the following statements so it can't be a typo. But such identity really confuse me, since if $L=T$ this is deifinitely true. But then it also gives $\Omega_{\mathbf{L}/X}^1 \simeq \pi_{\mathbf{L}}^* L^\vee$ and thus $L \simeq T$ necessarily, which cannot hold for a general torsor $L$.
So which step did I make a mistake/misinterpretation?

A torsor $\mathcal L$ over a vector group $\mathbf{T}$ is not a locally free sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules. If $\mathcal L$ is a $\mathbf{T}$-torsor, with local trivializations $s_i \in \Gamma(U_i,\mathcal L)$, then $s_i - s_j = t_{ij}$ for some sections $t_{ij} \in \Gamma(U_i \cap U_j,\mathbf{T})$. Since we are talking about the additive group $\mathbf{T}$, this means that sections of $\mathcal L$ do not have an additive structure (the equation $s_i - s_j = t_{ij}$ is not linear)! So $\mathcal L$ cannot be a sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules in a natural way. Furthermore, there is no zero section of $\mathcal L$, since $\mathcal L$ will not have a global section unless it is the trivial torsor.
If $\pi: \mathcal L \to X$ is the structure morphism, then $\pi_*\mathcal O_{\mathcal L}$ will not be a graded ring. Instead it has a filtration $F_{\leq n} \pi_*\mathcal O_{\mathcal L}$ by functions of degree at most $n$ on the fiber. (The property of a polynomial on a vector space having degree at most $n$ is invariant under translations.) This is discussed near (1.3.2) of Ogus-Vologodsky.

Thank you very much! I was too careless to notice that $L$ cannot be a sheaf of modules. Still I wonder what is the ''total space'' of $L$, just given by gluing the local data? Is there a neater way to form this?

The total space is given by gluing local data. Keeping notation above, by definition the total space is given by gluing $\mathbf{T}|{U_i}$ via the transition functions $t{ij}$.
